# go-automapper using time.Time field

Tags: go

I'm using [go-automapper](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PeteProgrammer/go-automapper) to copy values from db fields to a body post request. Both instances are the same type:

```
type MessageDTO struct {
    CreationDate time.Time          `bson:"creationDate" json:"creationDate,omitempty"`
}
```

at some point I tried to copy from one instance to another:

```
func entityToDTO(entity models.MessageDTO) models.MessageDTO{
    dto := &models.MessageDTO{}
    automapper.Map(entity, dto)
    return *dto
}
```

but it fails in the `time.Time` value:

> Error mapping field: CreationDate. DestType: models.MessageDTO .
> SourceType: models.MessageDTO. Error: Error mapping field: wall.
> DestType: time.Time. SourceType: time.Time. Error: reflect:
> reflect.Value.Set using value obtained using unexported field

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The fail reason is mentioned in the error message:

> Error: Error mapping field: wall ...
> Error: reflect: reflect.Value.Set using value obtained using unexported field

Refering to the source code of `time.Time`:

```
type Time struct {
    // wall and ext encode the wall time seconds, wall time nanoseconds,
    // ...
    wall uint64
    ext  int64

    // loc specifies the Location that should be used to
    // ...
    loc *Location
}
```

And the document of [go-automapper](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PeteProgrammer/go-automapper#Map) states:

> Values that are not exported/not public will not be mapped.
>
> It is a **design decision to panic**  when a field cannot be mapped in the
> destination to ensure that a renamed field in either the source or
> destination does not result in subtle silent bug.

So I think there is no direct way to get it. Maybe you could consider to copy the time data in `string` or other types that can be `Map`ped by `go-automapper`, then use interfaces like `(t *Time) UnmarshalBinary` `(t *Time) UnmarshalText` to convert to a `time.Time`.